# Name of pattern where you create an instance to call static methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Usually done to make legacy code testable.  For example, there might be a load of static calls like

```
int importantNumber = DataAccess.LoadValue();
```

and I create a class which can be instantiated to call these, which is normally behind an interface, like

```
public int LoadValue(){
    return DataAccess.LoadValue();
}
```

Then I can use DI or whatever and replace the original call with

```
int importantNumber = _dataAccessInstance.LoadValue();
```

Is there a name for this pattern?  I was thinking 'Adapter', but it seems more specific than that.

Comment: I was thinking of 'Adapter' as well.

Comment: I would call it an Object Oriented Wrapper. Anyway, what's in the name? :P

Comment: Adapter's used to map an interface to the interface we actually want -- this seems more like a straight-through mapping. My guess is proxy.

Comment: Naming's very important, @Unmesh!  In this case, I'm trying to find a good name for the 'adapter' class, which may include the pattern name.  Don't want to go confusing people with a bad name!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proxy.

It looks like one of the wrappers -- proxy, adapter or decorator. Decorator doesn't really fit as you're not adding any value; adapter fits if you're mapping from one interface to another; I think proxy is the answer, as you're using it to mediate access to the toolkit.

Could be facade if you're simplifying access to a subset of tools from a very large library of code.

Comment: Makes sense.  I might name the class 'xxxWrapper' instead of one of the specific wrapper patterns actually - seems a good compromise and less confusing than 'proxy', I think (even if that is the accurate pattern name).  Maybe someone needs to come up with a new name!

Comment: I tend to play around with the name Wrapper a lot, as Proxy always seems to come with baggage :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a proxy.

An adapter changes the interface of a class to make it easier to use with other clases

A facade is the creation of a single interface to make interacting with the interfaces of several objects easier.  It changes the level of abstraction.

A decorator does not change the interface but adds extra functionality

A proxy acts as a surrogate to another object with the same interface and same end functionality